# php Difference between -> and

Tags: php

I'm fairy new to php, but have a lot of OOP experience. I was just wondering why you do this in php.

What I think your meant to do:

```
$example->functionName();
```

What I thought you would've done:

```
$example.functionName();
```

(Please tell me if Ive got it all wrong)

So the question is, why do you use -> instead of . in php? Or is there no difference?

Comment: `.`is concatenation operator while `->`  is object operators

Comment: for more explanation go to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, `->` is the "object operator". It's used to access a property or method of an object. There are no specialties, just that PHP decided to use this symbol.

Additionally, there is `::` to access static methods and properties of classes (`MyClass::staticMethod()`).

`.` in PHP is used to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 2):

**"."(DOT)** is used for string **concatation** operation in php.

```
$str1='AB';
$str2='CD';
echo $str1.$str2; // ABCD
echo $str1.' '.$str2; // AB CD
```

While `$example->functionName();` refers that $example is an **object** and it is calling `functionName()` as class method.

Simply,
**`.`** is a **concatenation operator** and
**`->`** is an **object operator**.

Comment: Just a little note: `class method` is akin to `static method` - they operate not on the object but on the class. A method that operates specifically on a given object would be called `instance method`.